# Use Lerna with React Native?

Tags: npm, react-native, lerna

Is it possible to use Lerna ([lernajs.io](http://lernajs.io)) with React Native? I'm attempting to create new project with the following structure:

```
MyApp
  packages
    myapp-core
    myapp-mobile
    myapp-web
```

`lerna bootstrap` doesn't seem to have any issues with `core` or `web`, but `mobile` (which is a React Native project) refuses to find the `myapp-core` module.

I recall there is some issue with `npm link` in React Native. Is that what is causing the problem? Is this functionality something that will eventually exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like as of `react-native: 0.40.0`, lerna works as expected. I created a minimal demo app that uses a `shared` package to change the background color of both a React and a React Native app for those who are interested:

https://github.com/samcorcos/learna-react-native

Steps to reproduce:

1. clone the repo and `cd` in
2. `npm install`
3. `./node_modules/.bin/lerna bootstrap`

Then you can run each app (`npm start` for react, `react-native run-ios` for react native) and you'll see the background changed to red based on the input from the shared repo. When you add new packages, make sure you add the new package to each of the relevant `package.json` files, just as I've added `shared` to both the web and mobile projects.

Note that this project does not take advantage of Lerna's `--independent` versioning system.

Comment: Is there anything you did to get the symlink'd "shared"  working in packager? I dont understand how its working when packager doesnt support it (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find any solution @AshleyCoolman?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko I stopped looking for a solution - as it looks like whatever the problem is will be fixed eventually within RN. This Github issue is probably worth watching: https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler/issues/1#issuecomment-317806397

Comment: I switched to Haul https://github.com/callstack-io/haul and it works well

Comment: Looks great. Do you know if this would work fine with crna and expo too?

Comment: @samcorcos, have you checked it your lerna package works with yarn (`"useWorkspaces": true`)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments [React Native packager is not working with symlinks](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637). Which makes it impossible to use Lerna which creates symlinks to local subpackages from the same monorepo.

Fortunately, there is an alternative packager which supports symlinks. Works well for me so far https://github.com/callstack-io/haul/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a workspace to run lerna with react in native and web platform.

In fact having a web-mobile project in a lerna-style monorepo could be a great choice when you aim to share JS logic in your app.

Created the following monorepo as an example:

https://github.com/agrcrobles/react-native-web-workspace

For more information look into:

https://blog.hellojs.org/a-cross-platform-app-with-react-in-a-monorepo-9c6aa6aed818